# How do I map laptop "media keys"?

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

This is a fairly basic question from a noob perspective.

I am on Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon and want to change some of the keyboard shortcuts. (My laptop has a number of "media keys" on the same keys as the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys, used via a <kbd>Fn</kbd> modifier key. Things like screen brightness, volume, etc.)

I go to Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts and find the action I want to map to a key - "Increase screen brightness" for this example. Under Keyboard bindings I select one of the "unassigned" slots and press the key I want to map (<kbd>F4</kbd> has a big little sun symbol on it, so <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>) is the key I want). Instead of some keyboard combination shown in the field, some text is displayed - "AudioMicMute". So far so good, and this causes the screen to brighten when operating the key.

[image]

The problem is that now trying to set up the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> key to do "Decrease screen brightness", also tries to add "AudioMicMute" as a keyboard binding (there is a warning dialog that it was previously mapped to another action). If accepted, both the <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>F4</kbd> keys now cause the screen to darken...

So it would seem that "AudioMicMute" (and a number of similar bindings) are bound to some physical keys, and are in some cases bound to more than one key, as above. Unfortunately the Keyboard panel is not very helpful in this regard.

- How/where are these bindings set up?
- Can one see a complete list?
- Is it possible to change them/add new ones/delete existing ones?
- Can one see/change the actions preformed by each such binding?
- Am I even using the right terminology?

---

**Edit 1** to provide additional info as per comments. Running the command `xev -event keyboard`:

<kbd>F3</kbd> outputs:

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 26, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967215 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

<kbd>F4</kbd> outputs:

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 26, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967215 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Which seem identical.

---

**Edit 2** to provide additional info as per comments. Running the command `sudo evtest /dev/input/event4`:

```
sudo evtest /dev/input/event4
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x11 vendor 0x1 product 0x1 version 0xab41
Input device name: "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 1 (KEY_ESC)
    ... more keys ...
    Event code 58 (KEY_CAPSLOCK)
    Event code 59 (KEY_F1)
    Event code 60 (KEY_F2)
    Event code 61 (KEY_F3)
    Event code 62 (KEY_F4)
    Event code 63 (KEY_F5)
    ... more keys ...
    Event code 389 (KEY_DVD)
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
  Event type 17 (EV_LED)
    Event code 0 (LED_NUML) state 0
    Event code 1 (LED_CAPSL) state 0
    Event code 2 (LED_SCROLLL) state 0
Key repeat handling:
  Repeat type 20 (EV_REP)
    Repeat code 0 (REP_DELAY)
      Value    250
    Repeat code 1 (REP_PERIOD)
      Value     33
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1572444781.179157, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 1c
Event: time 1572444781.179157, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 28 (KEY_ENTER), value 0
Event: time 1572444781.179157, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

On <kbd>F3</kbd> press/release:

```
Event: time 1572444814.271993, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 81
Event: time 1572444814.271993, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 190 (KEY_F20), value 1
Event: time 1572444814.271993, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1572444814.278725, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 81
Event: time 1572444814.278725, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 190 (KEY_F20), value 0
Event: time 1572444814.278725, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

On <kbd>F4</kbd> press/release:

```
Event: time 1572444836.779556, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 81
Event: time 1572444836.779556, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 190 (KEY_F20), value 1
Event: time 1572444836.779556, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1572444836.786589, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 81
Event: time 1572444836.786589, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 190 (KEY_F20), value 0
Event: time 1572444836.786589, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

Comment: Can you run `xev -event keyboard`, to show the exact KeyPress and KeyRelease events generated by each of these keys?

Comment: Agreed with @JigglyNaga, I think there is a physical wiring issue. We should see the output of his command before anything else. If the output gives the same events for both keys it means that the keys are wired identically, at least from the point of view of the keyboard driver and you cannot distinguish them in any Linux distro which uses that particular driver.

Comment: I would expect to see `KeyPress` and `KeyRelease` events, which also show keysym values -- but there are a few possible reasons for those not appearing.   Could you next try `evtest`?  You may have to install the package of the same name.